# Repo Icon Color-Coding in Databricks: what is the difference between a black and a white folder icon

Tags: databricks, databricks-repos

In Databricks I have Repos with black and white icons. What does that mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black ones should belong to users/service principals, and white one - arbitrary folders that you may create to hold specific checkouts, like [here](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo), to separate staging/production Repos:

[image]